# Calculating weights for inverse probability weighting for the treatment effect on the untreated/non-treated

Tags: econometrics, stata, propensity-scores

I am trying to calculate weights for inverse probability weighting. For ATE and ATET the process is straightforward. For example in Stata:

```
predict ps if e(sample)

gen ate=1/ps if treatment==1
replace ate=1/(1-ps) if treatment==0

gen atet=1 if treatment==1
replace atet=ps/(1-ps) if treatment==0
```

My question is: how can i calculate the weights for the non-treated (ATENT)?

Comment: If this is purely about Stata then it is off topic here so you need to clarify your statistical question a bit more.

Comment: @Bel This is not a Stata question, so it would be helpful if you rewrote the question without using Stata code, but using mathematical notation. It would improve the chances of a good answer.

Answer (score 7):

For ATU, the weights on $y_i$ would be
$$
 w_i = \begin{cases}
      \frac{1 - \hat p(x_i)}{\hat p(x_i)} & \text{if}\ d_i=1 \\
      1 & \text{if}\ d_i=0,
\end{cases}
$$
where $d_i$ is the binary treatment indicator.

For ATT/ATET, the weights are
$$
 w_i = \begin{cases}
      1 & \text{if}\ d_i=1 \\
      \frac{\hat p(x_i)}{1-\hat p(x_i)} & \text{if}\ d_i=0
\end{cases}
$$

For ATE, the weights are
$$
 w_i = \begin{cases}
      \frac{1}{\hat p(x_i)} & \text{if}\ d_i=1 \\
      \frac{1}{1-\hat p(x_i)} & \text{if}\ d_i=0
\end{cases}
$$

You can find these formulas derived on pages 67-69 of *Micro-Econometrics for Policy, Program and Treatment Effects* by Myoung-jae Lee, except that I broke them into two pieces here.

Here's how I might do this in Stata, with native commands when possible and also by hand with a weighted regression of the outcome on a binary treatment dummy:

```
cls
set more off
webuse cattaneo2, clear
/* (0) Get the phats */
qui probit mbsmoke mmarried c.mage##c.mage fbaby medu
predict double phat, pr
/* (1a) ATE */
teffects ipw (bweight) (mbsmoke mmarried c.mage##c.mage fbaby medu, probit), ate
/* (1b) ATE By Hand */
gen double ate_w =cond(mbsmoke==1,1/phat,1/(1-phat))
reg bweight i.mbsmoke [pw=ate_w], vce(robust)
/* (2a) ATT */
teffects ipw (bweight) (mbsmoke mmarried c.mage##c.mage fbaby medu, probit), atet
/* (2b) ATT by Hand */
gen double att_w =cond(mbsmoke==1,1,phat/(1-phat))
reg bweight i.mbsmoke [pw=att_w], vce(robust)
/* (3) ATU by Hand Only */
gen double atu_w =cond(mbsmoke==1,(1-phat)/phat,1)
reg bweight i.mbsmoke [pw=atu_w], vce(robust)
```

This gives the following three effects of maternal smoking on newborn weight:

- ATU = -231.8782 grams
- ATT = -225.1773 grams
- ATE  = -230.6886 grams

Comment: @Bel Was this helpful?

Comment: Yes, this was very helpful, thank you so much Dimitriy! I have a related question for which i hope you do not mind also shedding some light into? The solution above (which i was after) is valid for the binary treatment case. If i have multiple treatments how can i calculate the weights by hand? My understanding is that i first estimate the propensity scores using a multinomial logistic regression. But it is unclear to me how one should proceed. I know that Stata has a native command for that, but i have been trying hard to understand the mechanics of the multiple treatment case and i am really

Comment: @Bel I would start a separate question on that, where you clarify what multiple treatments mean more precisely.

Comment: @Bel Also, if you think that I answered your original question, please select my answer using the check mark on the left.

Comment: Question: When estimating the ATT, aren't we examining only subjects in the treatment group (d=1)? Why would there be non-zero weight attached to the control group (d=0)?

Comment: @RobertF the point is to compare treated subjects to the untreated subjects most like the treated subjects based on covariates.  If you put 0 weight on all the untreated, there would be nothing to compare the treated to. The system would be perfectly singular unless you dropped treatment as an explanatory variable.

Comment: @MattP That sounds like the definition for the ATE - comparing similar similar subjects in the treated and untreated groups. It looks like the ATT (and ATU) estimate is using the same subjects as the ATE but has recalculated the weights. I'm not quite sure what the motivation is.

Comment: @RobertF The motivation is that for some group (treated, untreated, or both), you are trying to find matches that look similar in terms of probability of treatment but are opposite in terms of actual treatment assignment. The different types of weights accomplish this. You indeed start with the same people, but the weights ensure that they are treated differently depending on the parameter of interest.